# useState and map - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am using React for my FrontEnd.
I am using functional components. I am using Axios for fetching from an API.

In file **GetAllSuppliers.js**, I have the following:

```
function GetAllSuppliers(){
    const [supplier, setSupplier] = useState([]);



    useEffect(() => {
        return axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/suppliers/supplier/list`)
            .then((response) =>{
                setSupplier((prevState) =>({ ...prevState,
                    id: response.data.id ,
                    supplierTitle: response.data.supplierTitle,
                    supplierFirstName: response.data.supplierFirstName,
                    supplierLastName: response.data.supplierLastName,
                    companyName: response.data.companyName,
                    phoneNumber: response.data.phoneNumber,
                    otherPhoneNumber: response.data.otherPhoneNumber,
                    accountNumber: response.data.accountNumber,
                    email: response.data.email,
                    address: response.data.address,
                    website: response.data.website,
                    hourlyRate: response.data.hourlyRate,
                    typeOfGoods: response.data.typeOfGoods,
                    paymentTerms: response.data.paymentTerms,
                    createdAt: response.data.createdAt,
                    notes: response.data.notes,
                    products: response.data.products,
                    components: response.data.components
                }));

            }).catch((error) =>{
            setSupplier(error);
        })
    });

}

//other functions

export { GetAllSuppliers, other functions .... };
```

In **FileB.js**, I have the following code:

```
{GetAllSuppliers.supplier.map(t => <TableRow key={`supplier-${t.id}`} {...t} />)}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

What is a possible fix to the above error?

Comment: `GetAllSuppliers.supplier` is not valid, this should not be how you pass around props and state across componenets.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you're running `map()` on something that's undefined. 90% of the time, that means you're not handling the case that an axios call is in-progress and your variable isn't ready, yet (probably GetAllSuppliers, in this context).

Put in a conditional return that handles this case.

Answer (score 0):

In your `setSupplier` you are setting an object but you need to return an array to map.

Something like this:

````
  setSupplier((prevState) => {
      return [
        ...prevState,
        {
          id: response.data.id,
          supplierTitle: response.data.supplierTitle,
          supplierFirstName: response.data.supplierFirstName,
          supplierLastName: response.data.supplierLastName,
          companyName: response.data.companyName,
          phoneNumber: response.data.phoneNumber,
          otherPhoneNumber: response.data.otherPhoneNumber,
          accountNumber: response.data.accountNumber,
          email: response.data.email,
          address: response.data.address,
          website: response.data.website,
          hourlyRate: response.data.hourlyRate,
          typeOfGoods: response.data.typeOfGoods,
          paymentTerms: response.data.paymentTerms,
          createdAt: response.data.createdAt,
          notes: response.data.notes,
          products: response.data.products,
          components: response.data.components,
        },
      ];
    });
    ```
````

Comment: I am still getting the following error in FileB.js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined